# L'utilisation de "ne" + "que"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Laquelle des phrases suivantes est la plus correcte?

> Il n'est en France depuis qu'une semaine

> Il n'est en France que depuis une semaine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Il n'est en France que depuis 1 semaine.

C'est la plus naturelle et la seule correcte.

Le `n'* que` ici signifie `seulement`.

> Il est en France depuis que le covid a disparu.

> Il n'est en France que depuis que le covid a disparu.